# disable silverlight loading screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverlight, xhtml

Does anyone know how I could not show the default Silverlight loading blue balls and percentage.

It only shows up for a split second and I don't think I really need it as I am hiding my Silverlight under a jQuery slider.  By the time the user knows what happened it is loaded and ready to go.

One other problem is I believe my jQuery waits for the Silverlight to load before it runs.  Anyone know a way around this.  Is Silverlight a part of what it is looking for when it is checking $(document).ready()?

Edit:
Just thought I would add that I seemed to have answered my second question by implementing what AnthonyWJones suggested. Seems as though my jQuery doesn't wait or hang on Silverlight loading now and kicks off quickly and smoothly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable the default "loading screen" (its called the Splash screen in silverlight parlance) provide your own Xaml for the splash screen.

Create a "EmptySplash.xaml" in Visual Studio.  Place it as content in the **Web** project in the ClientBin folder.

Now add in the object element add the parameter:-

```
 <param name="splashscreensource" value="clientbin/EmptySplash.xaml" />
```

Comment: That is correct sir, thanks. Actually just got back from implementing exactly what you suggested.  I did notice if you didn't have at least an empty Canvas with necessary namespaces in the empty splash xaml, IE 8/7 would crash.

Comment: @theDawckta: sorry I wasn't explicit enough when creating a xaml file "in Visual Studio" you don't get a zero length file.  What I meant was just the default template and nothing else.  In fact the right choice is "Silverlight 1.0 JScript Page" then just delete the superflous .js that is added.  That gets exactly what you describe.